# Clear many to many on multiple objects in Django

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

Is there any way to bulk clear object relations before delete() method?
I've got a model:

```
class Man(models.Model):
     girlfriends = model.ManyToManyField('Girl')
```

and want to delete all "Man" objects in views.py:

```
def delete_all_objects(request):
    men = Man.objects.all()

    #trying to clear objects. getting an error
    men.girlfriends.clear()

    men.delete()
    return HttpResponse("success")
```

Getting error:
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'girlfriends'.

Comment: See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/relations/ for details on relationships

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is correct, the queryset *doesn't* have a 'girlfriends' attribute.  This is because the queryset is a set of `Man` objects and each of *these* has the attribute

```
def delete_all_objects(request):
    men = Man.objects.all()
    for man in men:
        man.girlfriends.clear()
        man.delete()
    return HttpResponse('success')
```

I haven't tested this but it should be pretty close to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're also trying to delete all related girls, `men.delete()` will achieve exactly what you want. The intermediate table has a foreign key to `Man`, and deleting an object will by default delete all foreign keys pointing to it (unless you override the [`on_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) behaviour).